# Navigation between Page (Win 8.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I try to navigate to a different page. I'm using visual studio express 2012. But i've read that on win-phone 8.1 we need to use System.Windows.Controls.Frame. The problem is that i dont find Frame in my namespace, I just have primitive inside. I would like to know if there is a way to update this package to have it.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? And do you know if you created a Silverlight or a Universal project?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx) is for Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime apps.
NavigationService.Navigate is for Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 Silverlight apps.

If you're using Visual Studio 2012 then you have a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app. You need Visual Studio 2013 to write a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Silverlight apps use NavigationService.Navigate for page navigation. See 
[How to perform page navigation on Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx)

Your Windows Phone 8.0 app will run on Windows Phone 8.1 without modification. It just won't have access to the new Windows Phone 8.1 functionality.

When you get Visual Studio 2013 (I'd suggest the Community Edition) you'll be able to upgrade it to a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app. This will use the same NavigationService you use in a Silverlight 8.0 app.

The other option with Visual Studio 2013 is to write a Windows Phone Runtime app, which can be a Universal app sharing code with a Windows Store app (to run on Windows). Windows Runtime apps use the Windows.UI.Xaml namespace instead of System.Windows. Instead of NavigationService they use [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx). See [Quickstart: Navigating between pages (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx#the_frame_and_page_classes)

Comment: Thank you, but i dont find the reference to Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame, I dont have the Xaml class. And i dont know how to add it in my project. I'm now using 2013 visual studio express and i created a Windows Phone Silverlight, did i made something wrong ?

Comment: You need to create a Windows Phone Runtime app (the "Universal Apps" or "Windows Phone" templates) to use Windows.UI.Xaml. Silverlight apps (the "Windows Phone Silverlight" templates) use NavigationService.Navigate. You will need Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or newer to create Windows Phone Runtime apps.

Comment: Ok, thanks i just did it. But my app is not going to work on windows phone 8.0 right ? I'm using Httpwebrequest and i want to know if there is something better now or if it's still good to use it.

Comment: And i also try to you use dispatcher.BeginInvoke but it doesnt work so if someone have an idea of how to make it works ;).

Comment: So if I want that my app work on windows phone 8 i should create a silverlight app, I just not gonna have new features. Because my app need to work on 8.0.

Comment: Windows 10 is coming soon too lol, so i don't know if it's good to start a windows 8.1. They are some changes and i barely touched it, and the "community" is maybe more used to create windows 8.0 app, so easier to get more help i think. For exemple i have trouble with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(), i dont find it and it's the same with Stream.Close(), I dont find it on runtime app. Maybe just some details but could be bad at the end :(. And I want my app to run on win 8.0 lol.

Answer (score 0):

You shlould create Windows Phone Universal application instead of Silverlight.
When creating new project in Visual Studio you shloud choose: Store Apps-> Windows Phone Apps -> There will be two types of projects: Silverlight (in parentheses there will be Windows Phone Silverlight) and Universal (in parentheses there will be Windows Phone) so you should choose second option.

After creating new project you can navigate form one Page to another using:

Framne.Navigate...

Hope I helped.

Comment: Yes Thank you, i created a Windows Phone universal app.